# jquery toggle child div open by clicking on parent class?

Tags: jquery

I have 5 occurences of my div class 'select'

```
<select>
<option_underlay> - css display:none
<select>
<option_underlay> - css display:none
<select>
<option_underlay> - css display:none
<select>
<option_underlay> - css display:none
<select>
<option_underlay> - css display:none
```

I also have underneath each 'select' div a child div called 'option_underlay'

I am using jquery as follows:

```
<script>

$(".select").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().next('.option_underlay').toggle();

});

</script>
```

this works by opening/toggling the corresponding  div underneath my parent div 'select'. So if a user clicks on the top 'select' then 'option_underlay' beneath the top 'select' div will open.

This works fine and am happy with the result. So if a user has clicked on the top div 'select' and this toggles/opens the 'option_underlay' div beneath.

But now if they go to the second 'select' div without closing the first 'option_underlay' they will have two occurence of 'option_underlay' the one underneath the first 'select' and the one under the second 'select'

So how can i close the first 'option_underlay' after a user has moved on to the second select? so there can never be more than one 'option_underlay' displayed at once?

Hope someone can help with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an actual HTML example so answers can be mocked up (e.g. in JSFiddle or a code snippet) :) You have `option_underlay` as an `element`, but refer to it as a `class` in the code.

Comment: `$(this).find('.option_underlay').toggle();`?

Comment: @Arun P Johny: "underneath" is ambiguous in the question. The HTML shown is invalid/incomplete.

Comment: $(this).parent.find('.option_underlay').css('display', 'none');
Then toggle the correct .option_underlay. I guess you could use .hide() and not .css('display', 'none') as well.